# How can i get the day in the datepicker javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker

this is my javascript code i get from some sites. But it just give me the  day month and year like (01-06-2019/ 01-07-2019/01-08-2019), and i want to output the correct day.

what can i change here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#monthPicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,

        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

            $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('MM yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));
            //$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            $(this).datepicker('refresh');
        }
    });

    $("#monthPicker").focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").show();
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
            my: "center top",
            at: "center bottom",
            of: $(this)
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: in which format you  want to display date  ?

Comment: @MannanBahelim day-month-year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#monthPicker").datepicker({
        todayHighlight: true,
        format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        setDate: new Date(),
        autoclose: true
    });
```

Decorate your textbox with date format.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "11", @readonly = true })
```

For more custom format visit : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings